# How to exclude specific user in get-eventlog

Tags: powershell, event-log, get-eventlog

I have the following script

```
get-eventlog -LogName Security -InstanceId 4663 -after (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1) -before (Get-Date) |
Select TimeWritten, @{Name="Account Name";Expression={ $_.ReplacementStrings[1]}}, @{Name="Object Name";e= {$_.ReplacementStrings[6]}}  |
Export-Csv "archive $(Get-Date -UFormat "%m.%d.%Y").csv" -NoType
```

I have tried adding a Where statement

`@{Name="Account Name";Expression={ $_.ReplacementStrings[1]} -notlike "user"}`

or

`$_.username -notlike "user"`

however neither seems to affect the outcome of the log.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution wound up using -NotMatch instead of -notlike

Pulled from https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/d6a2e073-ada4-4b4f-8cd5-1ebe9256fcfe/geteventlog-and-message-details?forum=winserverpowershell

```
get-eventlog -LogName Security -InstanceId 4663 -after (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1) -before (Get-Date) | 
Where {$_.message -notmatch "Account Name:\s*user*"} |
Select TimeWritten, @{Name="Account Name";Expression={ $_.ReplacementStrings[1] }}, @{Name="Object Name";e= {$_.ReplacementStrings[6]}}  |
Export-Csv "archive $(Get-Date -UFormat "%m.%d.%Y").csv" -NoType
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `-Like` and `-Notlike`, you have to specify a wildcard, using the asterisk *

Like this:

```
get-eventlog -LogName Security -InstanceId 4663 -after (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1) -before (Get-Date) |
    Where-Object {$_.username -notlike "*UserName*"} | 
        Select TimeWritten, @{Name="Account Name";Expression={ $_.ReplacementStrings[1]}}, @{Name="Object Name";e= {$_.ReplacementStrings[6]}}  |
            Export-Csv "archive $(Get-Date -UFormat "%m.%d.%Y").csv" -NoType
```